# Как перегрузить AsyncCallback?

Tags: c#, асинхронность

Суть вопроса такова:

Ранее в приложении был такой запрос, работающий через WebClient:

```
            WebClientGetSomething = new WebClient();
            WebClientGetSomething.DownloadStringCompleted += delegate(object getSender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs _e)
            {
                WebClientGetSomething_DownloadStringCompleted(getSender, _e, someExtraParameter);
            };
            WebClientGetSomething.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri(url, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));

            private void WebClientGetSomething_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e, SomeExtraParameter someExtraParameter)
            {
               // Делаем что-то
            }
```

Внезапно, произошло некое событие и пришлось переписывать все запросы через HttpWebRequest-ы.

В случае, если бы дополнительного параметра не было, это выглядело бы примерно так:

```
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
            request.Method = "GET";
            request.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
            request.CookieContainer.Add(new Uri(url, UriKind.Absolute), StoredCookieCollection._CookieCollection);
            request.BeginGetResponse(new AsyncCallback(WebClientGetSomething), request);

           private void WebClientGetSomething(IAsyncResult asynchronousResult)
           {
              // делаем что-то
           }
```

Соответственно возникает вопрос, как в WebClientGetSomething передать дополнительно объект типа SomeExtraParameter?

P.S. Вопрос строго говоря относится к Windows Phone, но тут мне важнее понять принцип, как это можно сделать. Надеюсь, все понятно объяснил.

---

**Решение**

```
 public class ExtendedHttpWebRequest: HttpWebRequest
    {
        public object control { get; set; }
    }
```

---

```
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(indexesUrl);
            request.Method = "GET";
            request.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
            request.CookieContainer.Add(new Uri(url, UriKind.Absolute), StoredCookieCollection.cookieCollection);
            ExtendedHttpWebRequest extendedWebRequest = new ExtendedHttpWebRequest();
            extendedWebRequest.control = sender;
            request.BeginGetResponse(new AsyncCallback(WebClientGetSomething), extendedWebRequest);
```

---

```
private void WebClientGetSomething(IAsyncResult asynchronousResult)
        {
            ExtendedHttpWebRequest extendedRequest = (ExtendedHttpWebRequest)asynchronousResult.AsyncState;
            object o = extendedRequest.control;
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы в качестве второго параметра метода `BeginGetResponse` передаёте `request`. Создайте небольшой вспомогательный класс, куда положите и `request` и всё необходимое.

```
public class MyState
{
    public HttpWebRequest Request { get; set; }
    public SomeExtraParameter Extra { get; set; }
}

MyState state = new MyState();
state.Request = request;
state.Extra = new SomeExtraParameter();
request.BeginGetResponse(new AsyncCallback(WebClientGetSomething), state);
```

Comment: Сделал несколько иначе(в данном случае будут проблемы либо с BeginGetResponse, либо с приведением типов в GetSomething), но в общем идея годная.

Comment: Какие проблемы с BeginGetResponse?

Приведение нужно будет одно - "as MyState"

Comment: Туплю, вставил не тот параметр в BeginGetResponse() :) Все верно